# Create an array key-value data structure -Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular8

I'm new to angular 8.
 I would like to create a data structure like this, but the typescript linter is complaining:

```
const x = {
    ['element1', 'element2'] : ['other1', 'other2'],
    ...
}
```

I wonder if it is possible to create such a data structure, without making the linter angry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not really about the linter or typescript. What you wrote there is not valid JS syntax. You could use a Map, but that will not equality compare the arrays properly. I would just concatenate the strigns to form a key

Comment: If you want to link tuples to tuples (talking more generally here as the mathematical ones, not the TS construct), then you should probably use a Map, as mentioned. However, if you want to use *any* valid representation of the tuple to lookup another, then you probably need to define your own Tuple class that has a custom equality implementation...although I'm not sure if this works for default Map. It might disregard the standard API for comparisons.

Comment: It doesn't seem like populating a Map with custom objects would work. [This is the algorithm used to fetch values from a Map when the key is an object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluenonnumeric). It literally only checks for the same object, does not try use well known symbols or properties for comparison. So, perhaps you need a custom Map instance. Perhaps you can subclass the vanilla one and provide new implementation for `set` and/or `get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is not valid Object computed property syntax in ES6. So we can't do it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Alternatively, we could try with Map

```
const map = new Map()
map.set(['element1', 'element2'], ['other1', 'other2'])
```

In TS:

```
const map = new Map<[string, string], [string, string]>()
map.set(['element1', 'element2'], ['other1', 'other2'])
```

Comment: And if the values were more than two in the arrays inside map?

Answer (score 1):

`Object` key is only `string` or `Symbol` types, but you can use `Map` with 1 problem

```
type MyType = [string, string]
const m: Map<MyType, MyType> = new Map();

const key:MyType = ['element1', 'element2'];
const value: MyType = ['other1', 'other2'];

m.set(key, value);

console.log(m.get(key)); // <- work!
console.log(m.get(['element1', 'element2'])); // <- not work
```